# How do I find out whether an element with that ID exists or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I do a:

```
console.log($('#test'));
```

I know that test doesn't exist. If I do a console.log, it doesn't output undefined/null. Rather it ouputs something like an empty array and when I check that array it looks like it returns the jQuery object itself.

I also tried:

```
if ($('#test')){
    //do something
}
```

But it still doesn't work. I want to know whether the ID I am selecting exists on page or not. How do I do that using jQuery?

Comment: If you check the [`$()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery) you'll notice it says _"If no elements match the provided selector, the new jQuery object is "empty"; that is, it contains no elements and has_ `.length` _property of 0."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, objects are always *truthy*, so using it in that fashion will always pass the condition.

You need to check the `length` property. A response of `0` is *falsy*, and will work as expected.

```
if ($('#test').length) { 
    // ...    
}
```

This is unlike `document.getElementById()`, which returns `null` if the element with that `id` attribute does not exist.

If this is confusing, you could always write a quick jQuery plugin.

```
$.fn.exists = function() {
    return !!this.length;
};
```

You can then call `exists()` on a jQuery collection, to ensure that selector has matched at least one item.

Comment: Cool! Thanks Alex. But what is !!? Can I not do this.length > 0?

Comment: Instead of return !!this.length; can I not do return this.length > 0;

Comment: @Jack Yes you can, and it will do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

It's something like 20x faster to do this:

```
if (document.getElementById("test"))
```

compared to the jQuery operation to just determine if a DOM object with that id exists in the page.  jQuery can do a lot for you, but when its general selector engine and general object structure isn't needed, it's not the quickest way to do things.

As others have said, `$("#test")` is always a valid jQuery object, even if `#test`doesn't exist.  If the `#test` object doesn't exist, then `$("#test")` will be a jQuery object that has no DOM objects in it (the internal array will have a `.length === 0`), but it's still a valid object.

Comment: yes you are right but when we have a class as selector then best and the shortest way to do is $(".test").length

Answer (score 1):

Use '(' and ')' for 'if' statements, and check if the returned array has length greater than 0:

```
if ($('#test').length > 0){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like this

```
if ($('#test').length > 0){
    alert('hi')
  }else
  {
     alert('hello')
  }
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X5V8S/)  ​

Answer (score 1):

best way for this is to check length of the selected element

```
if ($('#test').length > 0){
    //do something
}
```

But if you want to create a exist function jQuery welcomes you just add the line in your script

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
```

and now you can Check if element exist or not

```
if ($(selector).exists()) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if ($('#test').length > 0){
    //do something
}
```

the length tells you how many items were selected if it is 0 no element has the id test.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log($('#test'));
```

This won't print the value because it represents the object found in the DOM with the id test.
If you want to get values, use $("#test").val(); or $("#test").html();

If you want to check existence, do the length test as suggested above.

Also, if you're testing for the existence of a generated element (something you added to the DOM), make sure you checkout .live (http://api.jquery.com/live/). This is need for all elements that are created after the page is loaded.

Comment: `.live()` doesn't have anything to do with testing whether an element exists. (And even for its actual purpose `.live()` has been superseded by both `.delegate()` and `.on()`.)

Comment: Thanks for that bit of. Thinking about it,that makes sense now. Thanks for the bit on .delegate() and .on().